# Filter content search by date and time of creation

Tags: date-time, content-search-web-part

I'm using a content search web part to show news on my site. I want to show the items following a publishing date and time. I know there's the parameter `StartDate <= {Today}`.

How can I make it work with time, e.g. `StartDate <= {time.now}`?